# How to restrict S3 access to users of Active Directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Need to create S3 bucket and few objects which are intranet facing. But users may not be having AWS access.

How to restrict S3 access to users of my companies Active Directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things,

1. Connective Active Directory to AWS IAM
2. Create Roles for users to whichever the way you want it to S3

**AD to IAM:**

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-connect-your-on-premises-active-directory-to-aws-using-ad-connector/

**S3 IAM Role based Access:**

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/

Hope it helps.